# SQL Server: Issues with data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, toad

```
SELECT pa.[type], (SUM(pa.Actions_Logged)/SUM(pi.Impressions_Served)) AS ActionRates  
from Performance_Actions pa
INNER JOIN Performance_Impressions pi
ON pa.Alternative = Pi.Alternative
GROUP BY pa.[type];
```

The above query generates an error:

```
Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
```

Both `pa.Actions_Logged` and `pi.Impressions_Served` are int and the result would be a decimal. Is this the problem?

The Tables are
pi:

```
Date       Alternative  Impressions_Served
05/04/2015      x           544432
05/04/2015      x           545990
18/04/2015      y           343325
06/04/2015      z           591316
06/04/2015      y                2
```

pa:

```
Date       Alternative  Actions_Logged  Type
05/04/2015     x            33         landing
01/04/2015     y             3         conversion
06/04/2015     k             8         landing
01/04/2015     x             3         conversion
18/04/2015     y             3         landing
```

Comment: what are datatypes of `Actions_Logged` and `Impressions_Served`

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande  Both are int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type of expression in `SUM` determines return type.

Try the following:

```
SELECT pa.[type], (SUM(CAST(pa.Actions_Logged as BIGINT ))/SUM(CAST(pi.Impressions_Served as BIGINT ))) AS ActionRates  
from Performance_Actions pa
INNER JOIN Performance_Impressions pi
ON pa.Alternative = Pi.Alternative
GROUP BY pa.[type];
```

Comment: Works now Thabk you. In case I need the result to be a percentage then could I modify this further?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT pa.[type], (isnull( SUM(pa.Actions_Logged),0)/isnull(SUM(pi.Impressions_Served),0)) AS ActionRates  
from Performance_Actions pa
INNER JOIN Performance_Impressions pi
ON pa.Alternative = Pi.Alternative
GROUP BY pa.[type];
```